# How all the jobs in pipeline must get done through 1 active runners out of all active runners?

Tags: gitlab, devops, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

There are multiple runners configured for a service i.e runner1, and runner2.
Both the runners are active.
There should be picked up either of 1 runner for all jobs/stages while triggering pipeline for a service.
Note:- For Both runners there are different machines allocated.

Could anyone pls give suggestion to achieve this.

I am new to DevOps and still exploring and learning.
Go through the article

But couldn't get anything.

Comment: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/easy-way-to-have-a-pipeline-executed-by-a-single-runner-or-how-to-keep-the-same-runner-for-all-jobs/63014

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve your goal.
For example using tags:

1. You have to provide the tag for each of your runners in settings.
2. Include the tag of runner in your .yaml file.
   If you will assign tag runner01 to one of your runners the example pipeline will looks like:

```
  - build

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."
  tags:
   - runner01
```

Comment: Can I add more than 1 tags. Can you elaborate more?